# Trying to make the height of my jquery dropdown menu adjust according to window resizing

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am editing this page: http://spicyyeti.com/story_archive.html
So far, the code for the dropdown menus looks like this:

```
    $(window).load(function() {
     $('.item + .dropdown').each(function () {
            $(this).attr('data-height', $(this).height()).height(0);
        });

     $('.item').click( function() {
        $dropdown = $(this).find('+ .dropdown');
        if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).removeClass('open');
            $dropdown.animate({ height:'0' }, 400, "swing", function () {
                $(this).hide();
            });
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('open');
            $dropdown.show().animate({ height: $dropdown.attr('data-height') }, 400, "swing");
        }
    });
```

If you click a dropdown menu and resize the page, whether you keep the menu open or reopen it, the height of the dropdown menu stays the same. The content within the dropdown menu adjusts, but the dropdown height staying too low hides the images (and it being too high looks gross). I want the dropdown height to adjust with the content inside. I'm trying to use this code:

```
     $(window).resize(function() {
        $dropdown.height(function(){
            $('.item + .dropdown').height();
            });
        });
```

But it's not working. Help?

Comment: "height" takes a value , not a callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
     $(window).resize(function() {
        $dropdown.height($('.item + .dropdown').height());
    });
```